# IMPORTRANGE to refer the function but not the value/result

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, importrange

There are 5 different spreadsheets, i.e. Master, 1, 2, 3, 4)

All cell A1 in 5 different spreadsheets have the same function e.g. `=count(B1:B5)`, they count the data in their own spreadsheet.

And I want to change the function `=count(B1:B5)` to `=count(B1:B20)` in all files (spreadsheets 1,2,3,4)

`IMPORTRANGE` can only refer to the value/data/result of Cell A1 in Spreadsheet Master but not the function

Are there any other functions to automate the change for all Cell A1 of all spreadsheets 1,2,3,4 when I change the function in Spreadsheet Master Cell A1?

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User three times.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be *not* change the child spreadsheets, but get the count directly in the Master spreadsheet, like this:

`=count( iferror( importrange("...put spreadsheet ID here...", "B1:B20") ) )`

If you do need to change the child spreadsheets, and only have four of them, the easiest solution would be to change them manually. If you need to do that often, consider using the `count(iferror(filter()))` pattern to make the formula adjust automatically to whatever change causes the need to edit the range in your current `count()` formula in the first place.

If there are not four but many more child spreadsheets, you may want to automate the process using a script. The script should process each spreadsheet in turn to do the necessary change. See the [processFilesInFolderRecursively_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/182948899?msgid=182993974) script for sample code.